# install php 8.0.11 on wamp and apache 2.4.46

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver, php-8

I am trying to install php 8 on my wamp with apache 2.4.46.

I did everything and followed the tutorials well.

I have my php 8.0.11 directory in wamp / bin / php, I have put the famous php8apache2_4.dll dll and yet I still have an error message:

[image: Error message about xe9 module]

the dll is present.

[image]

has anyone ever had the problem? what is this module sp \ xe9cifi \ xe9?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you install PHP8.0.11 using the ADDON or manually?

Comment: @RiggsFolly  manually

Comment: Remove all you did and run the ADDON which you can get from SourceForge or more easily from the [WAMPSERVER backup repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en)

Comment: Also look at the bottom of that page and download from the Tools section the utility called "Checks VC++ packages installed" and then if needed all the MSVC Runtimes from just below that on the same page